# Variable not being changed during recursive backtracking algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am using recursion and backtracking to solve a problem. I am updating the variable called `minimum` whenever a certain condition is met. However, despite the `minimum` variable being updated several times when the function returns, `minimum` is still set to it's original value.

I don't understand why because I am passing in a reference to the same place in memory and updating it when the base case is hit.

```
def minCost(self, costs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        depth, cost, prev_index, minimum = 0, 0, None, 10000

        def min_cost_recur(depth, cost, prev_index, n, minimum, costs):
            if depth == n:
                minimum = min(minimum, cost)
                return

            original_prev_index = prev_index*1

            for i in range(0, 3):
                if not i == original_prev_index:
                    cost += costs[depth][i]
                    depth += 1
                    prev_index = i
                    min_cost_recur(depth, cost, prev_index, n, minimum, costs)
                    depth-=1
                    cost -= costs[depth][i]
                    prev_index = original_prev_index

        min_cost_recur(depth, cost, -1, len(costs), minimum, costs)

        return minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the new value of `minimum` in your recursion otherwise it will never update:

```
def minCost(self, costs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        depth, cost, prev_index, minimum = 0, 0, None, 10000

        def min_cost_recur(depth, cost, prev_index, n, minimum, costs):
            if depth == n:
                minimum = min(minimum, cost)
                return minimum

            original_prev_index = prev_index*1

            for i in range(0, 3):
                if not i == original_prev_index:
                    cost += costs[depth][i]
                    depth += 1
                    prev_index = i
                    minimum = min(minimum, min_cost_recur(depth, cost, prev_index, n, minimum, costs))
                    depth-=1
                    cost -= costs[depth][i]
                    prev_index = original_prev_index
            return minimum
        minimum = min_cost_recur(depth, cost, -1, len(costs), minimum, costs)

        return minimum
```

This happens because `minimum` is not passed by reference but by value as it's an instance of an immutable type. When you where modifying its value inside the recursion, it was just creating a local nmae for minimum instead of changing the variable from parent scope.

Comment: I didn't know integers are immutable in Python. Thanks.